# AWS Lambda with multiple triggers (ALB, SNS...)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

**Context:**

All my stack is in Java.

I have the following setup:

- Backend application (A) that sends SNS notifications (among other stuff not important here).
- Lambda that is triggered by kinesis stream events (B) and processes them.

**NOTE:** A and B components cannot change its main behavior (explained above).

Then, I would like to have another lambda (C) which would process the SNS notifications sent by A and, also, the lambda B should invoke lambda C to obtain the SNS notifications processed.

For that, I was thinking to create a lambda C that would listen to both SNS and API rest calls:

- `SNSEvent`: it should process them and store them in a list.
- `APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent`: it should return that list.

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to have one AWS lambda to be called by multiple triggers?
- How the handler would look like?
- Is it a good practice?
- Do you see any better approach for my needs?

Comment: How would Lambda B get the notification from lambda C? Is C going to store the notification? SNS will invoke B whenever it gets a message, not when B invokes C.

Comment: I am thinking about the following:
[1. A sends SNS notifications to C
2. C reads the SNS notifications and stores them in a db
3. D ( another new lambda) exposes an endpoint through ALB and reads from DB
4. B calls D in order to get those processed values]

So, C and D would be new lambdas sharing the same module in the code and will share also the db.